# Pattern matching in Mathematica vs Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, pattern-matching, wolfram-mathematica

I find myself somewhat as ease with pattern matching using regular expression on Mathematica. Recently I started to use Haskell and I liked it way more than I did Mathematica.

I tried searching for regular expression in Haskell that work on equations or list but couldn't. There are examples on strings that  I found. If someone has some references/examples, please share it.

I am referring to pattern matching in terms of data rather than function definition as later is supported in both in similar way.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this myself, but I believe the OP is referring to [this kind of regular expression / pattern matching](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PatternMatchingFunctions.html)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor : Your assumption is correct, all those links have some examples and some examples are there on equations/polynomial manipulation/filter.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : I agree with your suggestion, I had it in my head as well but they are so close that I continued with it.

Comment: Haskell pattern machine is based on data constructors i.e the way you construct something, the same way you de-construct (pattern match) it. Regular expression doesn't fit this description. You can use some haskell libraries to use regular expressions though

Comment: @Ankur : please post some details as answer, so that I can explore it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : I just wanted to add and further clarify that in Haskell, pattern matching is usually associated with function definition, that's why I avoided using it.

Comment: Racket supports this: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html e.g. `(match "apple"
    [(regexp #rx"p+(.)" (list _ "l")) 'yes]
    [_ 'no])`. Unfortunately I don't believe this sort of thing exists in Haskell but you might be able to do it with template haskell.

Comment: @Wes : for string it exists I know, but not for algebraic equations/polynomials. I will search templates, thanks for hint.

Comment: @Blackbird This isn't actually true, pattern matching in a function signature is actually just a bit of sugar on top of the more general `case` expression

Comment: This might be what the HaRP extension (a.k.a. `RegularPatterns`) and [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/harp) were made for (PDF of paper [here](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/local_22484.pdf)), but that project has been pretty much dead for a few years.

Comment: @Rhymoid : I am thankful to you for this hint.